# Is it okay to call functions with threads in onCreate method?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance

I have written a ***function*** with thread that creates typefaces and later on assigns these typefaces to text views via handler. I have called this ***function*** in the ***onCreate*** method. So I was wondering if it is a good programming practice to call function with threads in the onCreate method. Will it effect the performance of my app.

Also, I haven't noticed any improvement in performance by using these threads. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView quickFactTitle, quickFactText, plioceneTitle, plioceneMya,
            plioceneInfo, mioceneTitle, mioceneMya, mioceneInfo;

    Typeface font, nFont, ntFont;

    EditText searchBox;

    LinearLayout toPlioList;

    Intent i;

    Handler textFontHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            applyFonts();
            return true;
        }
    });

   /* Handler textFontHandler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            applyFonts();
        }
    };*/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Initialize();
        i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreatureList.class);
        initFonts();
        // applyFonts();
    }

    public void openPlioList(View v) {
        i.putExtra("listType", 1);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private void initFonts() {
        Runnable fontR = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Fonts/futuristic.TTF");
                nFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Fonts/quicksand_book.otf");
                ntFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Fonts/quicksand_bold.otf");
                textFontHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        };
        Thread fontThread = new Thread(fontR);
        fontThread.start();
    }

    private void applyFonts() {
        quickFactTitle.setTypeface(font);
        plioceneTitle.setTypeface(ntFont);
        mioceneTitle.setTypeface(ntFont);
        quickFactText.setTypeface(nFont);
        plioceneInfo.setTypeface(nFont);
        mioceneInfo.setTypeface(nFont);
    }

    public void Initialize() {
        quickFactTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quick_fact_title);
        quickFactText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quick_fact_text);
        plioceneInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pliocene_info_txt);
        plioceneTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pliocene_title_txt);
        plioceneMya = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pliocene_mya_txt);
        mioceneTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.miocene_title_txt);
        mioceneInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.miocene_info_txt);
        mioceneMya = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.miocene_mya_txt);

        searchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);

        toPlioList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.to_plioList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: that is ok to do like you do

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please note that using threads doesn't increase overall speed of your apps. Actually using them just decrease speed of apps. As a note you should create your apps with as fewer number of threads as you can.

So, when they're useful? Threads are useful whenever you'd like to carry out an I/O operation, which wastes CPU cycles while it's waiting for a I/O operation to complete. I/O operations include:

- File I/O.
- Network I/O.
- Etc.

Bottom line: Bad use of threads does lower performance of your app.

---

In your case, I'm not certain whether `createFromAsset` should be done in a background thread or not. As I just checked out the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#createFromAsset(android.content.res.AssetManager,%20java.lang.String)), I've seen nothing about background threads.

However, if you're certain that should be done in background threads, your way of using threads is okay IMO.

Comment: IMO, threads should be used in other cases too, not just for I/O. Because modern devices have multiple cpu cores, you can fully use all that processing power with threads, so eg. for CPU intensive processing (eg. for Bitmap decoding), you can do multiple operations at the same time, vs having to do them sequentially, thereby speeding up your app. I do agree that asker's use of threads is somewhat questionable though.